# Existence of divisor of zero if $\operatorname{card}(A)\ge4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$A$ is a ring such that $a^2=a$ for all $a\in A$. I want to prove that if $\operatorname{card}(A)\ge4$ then $A$ has divisor of zero.

I proved that for $a\in A$ we have  $a+a=0$. In fact:
$$2a=(a+a)^2=a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2=4a\implies 2a=0$$
I don't know if this result is useful for my question and I haven't any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have at least four elements in our ring, pick an element $a$ in your ring that is not $0$ or $1$. Then you know that $a^2=a$ so that $a(1-a)=0$ but we know neither $a$ nor $(1-a)$ is zero, so we've found a zero divisor!

Notice that our proof only needed that $R$ needs to have at least three elements.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I'm tired and I need stop working because I didn't see this:-) Just one thing, the ring $A$ must have an even cardinal because regarded as a group and since every element has order 2 which divides the cardinal so this cardinal is $\ge4$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but an illustration of this statement.

In fact, $a^2=a$ mean your ring is composed of projectors.

Also, an element is a divisor of zero means it is not invertible, which is coherent with being a projector because the projection loses information into one direction and you cannot recreate it out of thin air.

For instance, let's look at this ring in the plane:

$\begin{array}{ll}
0=(0,0)\\
1=(x,y) & \text{identity function}\\
a=(x,0) & \text{projection on X-axis}\\
b=(0,y) & \text{projection on Y-axis}\\
\end{array}$

We have $ab=(x,0)(0,y)=(0,0)=0$ thus divisor of zero.

Also, in this case, $1-a=(x,y)-(x,0)=(0,y)=b$